# How to write more than one page at once in Winbond W25Q32JV

Tags: c, spi, memory, programming, flash

I am using Eclipse IDE for firmware development. I am using Quectel MC60 module with Winbond W25Q32JV (4 MB memory). The thing is that I am able to read/write single page.

I am facing issue with multiple page writing at once. I have to write multiple pages at once since I had erased the sector (consists of 16 pages).
Before writing one page, I had to erase 1 sector.

General algorithm for writing:

```
main()
{
// read from memory address adr

// erase sector (16 pages)

// write at address adr
}
```

I want to utilize memory pages for optimum performance. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks for your prompt response.
                                                                                                                               **My pseudocode  is like this:**

```
char buff[256];

sector_erase(0);   // erase first 16 pages

memset(buff,7,sizeof(buff));

for(int addr=0;addr<16;addr++)
    {
    write_enable();
    page_program();
    spi_write(addr,buff);    // write page one by one and hence increment the address 
    while(status_register);   // polling status register
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [datasheet](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q32jv%20spi%20revc%2008302016.pdf#page35), it’s clear that you cannot write more than one page in a single operation. For each page to be written, you’ll need to do the entire sequence of <write-enable>, <page-program> (or <quad-input-page-program>), and then poll the status register for completion. You’ll probably just want to put this sequence in a loop.

I don’t see a faster way to do this.

Comment: Edited the question. Check if it's correct method. Thanks for your suggestions